# Am I finding this $x$-value correctly?

Tags: quadratics

If the flight path of a cricket ball is given by:
$$y = \frac{1}{3}x - \frac{1}{60}x^2$$
And a fielder standing originally at $(10, 0)$ catches the ball when it is $1.5$ units above the ground, to find how far he ran you would simply sub $1.5$ in as $y$ and solve for $x$ from a quadratic and take into consideration where he started at, correct?  I've tried this but the number I get is not rational.  It does not factorise, so I filled into the quadratic formula to get:
$$10 + \sqrt{10}$$ or $$10 - \sqrt{10}$$

It just seems odd to me, so I'm checking here that I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: That looks right.  In this particular case, the distance ran by the fielder works out unambiguously.

Comment: Of course, it is not particularly realistic. The smaller solution corresponds to catching the ball when it is still rising.